# C#/SQL Error: Am getting error in my project

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[coc_ConfirmUploadRepayments]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
(@username nvarchar(500),
@computername nvarchar(50),
@compdomain nvarchar(50),
@ipadress nvarchar(50),
@Response nvarchar(50) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
DECLARE @AmortizationId int;
DECLARE @MemberId nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @MemberNo nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @PaymentModeId nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @product nvarchar(500); 
DECLARE @repaymentDate date;
DECLARE @PrincipalPortion decimal(18,2);
DECLARE @interestPortion decimal(18,2);
DECLARE @appliedInterest decimal(18,2);
DECLARE @LoanNumber nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @LoanId nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @PayableAmount decimal(18,2);
DECLARE @amountpaid decimal(18,2);
DECLARE @Penalties decimal(18,2);
DECLARE @AppliedPenalties decimal(18,2);
DECLARE @Date date;
DECLARE @ID int;
DECLARE @RefNo nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @ReceivedFrom nvarchar(50);



--DECLARE @TransactionCode nvarchar(50) = (SELECT [dbo].GetTransactionCode())
DECLARE uploadrepayments CURSOR
FOR 
SELECT  LoanRepaymentUploadId,MemberNo,LoanNo,Date,Amount,ReceivedBy,PaymentMethod FROM ACC0416 WHERE Confirmed=0
Open uploadrepayments
FETCH NEXT FROM uploadrepayments INTO @ID,@MemberNo,@LoanNumber,@repaymentDate,@amountpaid,@ReceivedFrom,@PaymentModeId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS<>-1
BEGIN       
SELECT @LoanId  = ((SELECT MAX(LoanId) FROM ACC0110)+1);    
SELECT @MemberId =(SELECT MemberId FROM ACC0010 WHERE MemberNo=@MemberNo);
DECLARE @CountMemberProductId int=(SELECT COUNT(productid) FROM ACC0110 WHERE MemberId=@MemberId)
DECLARE @ReceiptNumber nvarchar(500) = (SELECT [dbo].GetReceiptNo())
DECLARE @TransactionCode nvarchar(50) = (SELECT [dbo].GetTransactionCode())         
DECLARE @COUNTMemberID int=(SELECT COUNT(MemberId) FROM ACC0010 WHERE MemberNo=@MemberNo)
IF (@COUNTMemberID=1 OR @CountMemberProductId=1 )
BEGIN   
    SELECT @product =(SELECT productid FROM ACC0110 WHERE MemberId=@MemberId ); 
    SELECT @AmortizationId=(SELECT AmortizationId FROM ACC0121 WHERE LoanNumber=@LoanNumber);
    SELECT @PrincipalPortion=(SELECT PrincipalPortion FROM ACC0121 WHERE LoanNumber=@LoanNumber);
    SELECT @interestPortion=(SELECT interestAmount FROM ACC0121 WHERE LoanNumber=@LoanNumber );
    SELECT @appliedInterest=(SELECT appliedInterest FROM ACC0121 WHERE LoanNumber=@LoanNumber );
    SELECT @PayableAmount=(SELECT TotalAMountPayable FROM ACC0121 WHERE LoanNumber=@LoanNumber );
    SELECT @Penalties=(SELECT Penalties FROM ACC0121 WHERE LoanNumber=@LoanNumber );
    SELECT @AppliedPenalties=(SELECT AppliedPenalties FROM ACC0121 WHERE LoanNumber=@LoanNumber );  

    INSERT INTO ACC0122 (PaymentModeId,AmortizationId,MemberId,Product,LoanNumber,PrincipalPortion,Interestportion,AppliedInterest,Penalty,Appliedpenalty,PayableAmount,PaidAmount,DatePaid,ReceiptNumber,ReferenceNumber,ReceivedFrom) 
    VALUES (@PaymentModeId,@AmortizationId,@MemberId,@product,@LoanNumber,@PrincipalPortion,@interestPortion,@appliedInterest,@Penalties,@AppliedPenalties,@PayableAmount,@amountpaid,@Date,@ReceiptNumber,@RefNo,@ReceivedFrom)

    INSERT INTO ACC0229 (LoanNumber,MemberId,PrincipalPortion,Interestportion,Penalties,PrincipalDebitCOAID,PrincipalCreditCOAID,InterestDebitCOAID,InterestCreditCOAID,PenaltiesDebitCOAID,PenaltiesCreditCOAID,DateRepaid,Posted)
    VALUES(@LoanNumber,@MemberId,@PrincipalPortion,@interestPortion,@Penalties,99,57,99,4,99,7,@Date,0)

    UPDATE ACC0121 SET AmountPaid=@amountpaid,AppliedPenalties=@AppliedPenalties,AppliedInterest=@appliedInterest WHERE AmortizationId=@AmortizationId 
    SET @Response='Successfully posted'
    --New Loan Balance sql
    --declare @bal decimal(18,3)=(select sum(paidamount) as PaidAmount1 from acc0122 where loannumber=@LoanNumber)-(select sum(paidamount) as PaidAmount1 from acc0122 where loannumber=@LoanNumber)
    --update ACC0121 set LoanBalance=@bal where LoanNumber=@LoanNumber and AmortizationId=@AmortizationId

END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @Response='Some members not registered or do not have respective accounts'
END
FETCH NEXT FROM uploadrepayments INTO @ID,@MemberNo,@LoanNumber,@repaymentDate,@amountpaid,@ReceivedFrom,@PaymentModeId,@product
END
CLOSE uploadsavings

DEALLOCATE uploadrepayments

EXECUTE Coc_TrackUser_400 'CONFIRMED LOAN REPAYMENTS',@TransactionCode,@username,@computername,@compdomain,@ipadress
SET @Response='Successfully confirmed'
END
```

This is my stored procedure.Its Loading most of the information from another table using the CURSOR uploadrepayments. Then Loop through the data and insert the data into table ACC0122,ACC0229 and ACC0121.

Comment: and the short exception message is ?

Comment: Looks like a connection error, nothing to do with the procedure. Can you debug?